# Java: How would i iterate through an array that is not full to its max size.

Tags: java, arrays

For my problem I had to write a method that would take user input and create an array of objects. However any number of objects can be created. So the array size is 100 but only 2 elements of the array are filled. Now when I use my getAverage method I get a null point exception after it goes past the stored objects.

```
public class Item{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of objects to input in the array");
    int numOfEntries = input.nextInt();

    Item[] itemArray = new Item[100];
    Item.input(itemArray, numOfEntries);
    System.out.println(Item.getAverage(itemArray));
    //Item.input(itemArray);
} 
public static void input(Item[] arr) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double pricesAdded = 0;
    double average = 0;
    double numofEntries = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter item");
        String item = input.next();

        System.out.println("price");
        double price = input.nextDouble();

        if (price == -1) break;

        arr[i] = new Item(item, price);
        numOfItems++;
    }

    for( int j = 0; j < numofEntries; j++) {
        if(arr[j].getName().equals("peas") || arr[j].getName().equals("Peas")) {
            for( int k = 0; k < numOfItems; k++) { 
                pricesAdded = pricesAdded + arr[k].getPrice();
            }
            average = pricesAdded / numofEntries;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(average == 0) System.out.println("No average output " + average);
        else System.out.println("The average is " + average);



   for ( int i = 0; i < numofEntries; i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i].toString());
}

public static double getAverage(Item[] itemArr) {
    double pricesAdded = 0;
    double average = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < itemArr.length; i++) {
        if(itemArr[i].getName().equals("peas") || itemArr[i].getName().equals("Peas")) {
            for( int k = 0; k < itemArr.length; k++) { 
                if ( itemArr[k].getPrice() == 0.0) break;
                pricesAdded = pricesAdded + itemArr[k].getPrice();

            }
            average = pricesAdded / itemArr.length;
            break;
        }
    }
    return average;
}
```

Comment: Keep a counter; use a sentinel value; create a new array +1 length (uhg complexity, but it world "work"); or, my recommendation, use a List and keep life simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a null check:

```
if (arr[j] != null) {
// your logic
}
```

A better approach is to use a data structure like `ArrayList`, since they can grow as you add elements.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why others did not notice, but this code has serious issues.

```
public static void input(Item[] arr) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double pricesAdded = 0;
    double average = 0;
    double numofEntries = 0;//initialized to 0 and never changes
    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter item");
        String item = input.next();

        System.out.println("price");
        double price = input.nextDouble();

        if (price == -1) break;

        arr[i] = new Item(item, price);
        numOfItems++;//no declaration found
    }

    for( int j = 0; j < numofEntries; j++) {
        if(arr[j].getName().equals("peas") || arr[j].getName().equals("Peas")) {
            for( int k = 0; k < numOfItems; k++) { 
                pricesAdded = pricesAdded + arr[k].getPrice();
            }
            average = pricesAdded / numofEntries;//price added divided by 0              
            break;
        }
    }
```

You can fix these and use a global variable to keep the count.

```
public class Item{

    static int numOfEntries;//global variable

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of objects to input in the array");
        numOfEntries = input.nextInt();//initialize the global variable

        Item[] itemArray = new Item[100];
        Item.input(itemArray, numOfEntries);
        System.out.println(Item.getAverage(itemArray));
        //Item.input(itemArray);
    }
```

and when you loop, use

```
 for( int j = 0; j < numOfEntries; j++)
```

and this will fix your problem because user specifically enters the number of items.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just check for null before using the value:

```
for( int j = 0; j < numofEntries; j++) {
    if(arr[j] == null){
        continue; //break? if you hit one null, can you gurantee everything after is null?
    }
}
```